# Upload a video file in apache server using php

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a video file using php.
The User will get a page where he will get an option to upload a file and then, it will get uploaded to the server. My script works fine for the jpg and png. But its not working for mp4. It does not give any error.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","mp4");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 20971520000000  ){
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/Library/www/yes/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }
  else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit"/>
     <ul>
        <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
        <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
        <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
     </ul>
  </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please, say what error it shows.

Comment: As I mentioned above, no error !!

Comment: how big is your mp4?

Comment: Does your script pass through the check of possible extensions `in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false`?

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL); to the first line, and do a print_r($_FILES); on the second line for debugging purposes. And tell the output.

Comment: Sent file: 
Notice: Undefined index: image in /Library/www/yes/upload2.php on line 40
File size: 
Notice: Undefined index: image in /Library/www/yes/upload2.php on line 41
File type: 
Notice: Undefined index: image in /Library/www/yes/upload2.php on line 42

Comment: On furthee debugging I noticed that I am able to upload file less than 2 mb. I tried changing the upload_max_filesize = 20M to 200000M. But Still it dosent work !! Any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set/changed upload_max_filesize in php.ini the default (2mb) is preventing uploads of files greater than 2mb.

Comment: did you restart apache? `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`